# DataGridView Preserve Selected Index and Scroll Position after update and reload

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I have some problem, don't now how to preserve the scroll position in a `DataGridView`.

I have over 1000+ rows and scrolling back to edited row is painful. How can I preserve the scroll position and scroll to the edited row after refreshing data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Save the row index, do your refresh, then set the `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` property.

```
int index = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

/*
 * Your Refresh Code
 */

dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = index;
```

Comment: This code works but before scrolling to last scrolling position, scrollbar jumps to top for a fraction of second.
I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: @NiravParsana I am unable to test this currently, but perhaps try wrapping this code in `dataGridView1.SuspendLayout()` and `.ResumeLayout()`.  If not that, maybe something else [to suspend the grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4649995/3773066) will work?

Answer (score 5):

You can get the current row index before reloading data:

```
int currentIndex= dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
```

Then after reloading data, you can use either of these options:

- To scroll and set the current row, set [`CurrentCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell(v=vs.110).aspx).
- To only scroll, set [`FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex(v=vs.110).aspx).

Scroll And set current row:

```
this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell =  this.DataGridView1.Rows[currentIndex].Cells[0];
```

Scroll:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = currentIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    if (dataGridView != null &&
        dataGridView.CurrentRow != null)
            this.Invoke(new Action(GetScrollingIndex));
    UpdateTable();
    if (dataGridView != null &&
        dataGridView.CurrentRow != null)
            this.Invoke(new Action(SetScrollingIndex));
}
void GetScrollingIndex()
{
    scrollingIndex = dataGridView.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex;
}
    
void SetScrollingIndex()
{
    dataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = scrollingIndex;
}
```

Comment: This is still a little choppy because the user loses focus of the scroll bar when updating, but it works