# Highlight a row in Datagridview based on textbox value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Good Evening.

I have a program in VB.Net that refreshes datagridview after you edit some data my problem here is im populating over 1000 records.

Let say Im editing row 999 and after i click update the data will refresh causing the datagridview to return at the top (The blue highlighter)

My goal here is how can I maintain it to its current position after update?

My solution here is highlight the data where Textbox1 = value

Is this possible like this?

```
'SAMPLE CODE
Datagridview1.Column(0).value.BlueHighLighter = Textbox1.text
```

Pls see my code on how i refresh DGV

```
  Dim con11 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=192.168.2.87;userid=root;password=admin1950;database=inventory")
        Dim sql1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("select PONo,ItemCode,Description,QtyPack,PackUoM,QtyStan,StanUoM,UnitPrice,Total,Remarks,ExpiryDate from Receiving where RINo = '" & Add_Receiving_Items.TextBox1.Text & "';", con1)
        Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet
        Dim adapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
        con1.Open()
        adapter1.SelectCommand = sql1
        adapter1.Fill(ds1, "MyTable")
        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
        con1.close()
        With Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1()
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "PO No"
            .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Item Code"
            .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Description"
            .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Quantity/Pack"
            .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "Packaging UoM"
            .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "Quantity/Pc"
            .Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "Standard UoM"
            .Columns(7).HeaderCell.Value = "Unit Price"
            .Columns(8).HeaderCell.Value = "Total"
            .Columns(9).HeaderCell.Value = "Remarks"
            .Columns(10).HeaderCell.Value = "Expiry Date"
        End With

        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.Columns.Item(0).Width = 80
        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.Columns.Item(1).Width = 80
        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).Width = 120
        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).Width = 86
        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.Columns.Item(4).Width = 68
        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.Columns.Item(5).Width = 75
        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.Columns.Item(6).Width = 68
        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.Columns.Item(7).Width = 70
        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.Columns.Item(8).Width = 80
        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.Columns.Item(9).Width = 105
        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.Columns.Item(10).Width = 63
        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter
        Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter
        With Add_Receiving_Items.DataGridView1
            .RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
            .AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lavender
        End With
```

TYSM for future help

Comment: Save the index of the current row. When grid is refreshed set the selected row off that saved index.

Comment: How sir? I will edit my post for you to see how do i refresh my DGV

Comment: Pls see the edited file

Comment: [DataGridView Preserve Selected Index and Scroll Position after update and reload](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34778978/3110834)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataGridView.CurrentRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow(v=vs.110).aspx) property. But please be aware that `CurrentRow` is `ReadOnly`, you must use `CurrentCell`

Before refreshing your data store `Dim oldIndex = DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index`  and after the refresh set `DataGridView.CurrentCell = DataGridView.Rows(oldIndex).Cells(0)`

**EDIT:**

**How to test the Code**

Create a form with a `Button1`  and a `DataGridView1` with two columns and paste the following code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i = 1 To 5
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add("foo" & i, "bar" & i)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim currentIndex = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        currentIndex += 1
        If currentIndex >= DataGridView1.Rows.Count Then currentIndex = 0

        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(currentIndex).Cells(0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT:**

```
Dim oldIndex = DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index
'Put your code here on how you refresh your data
DataGridView.CurrentCell = DataGridView.Rows(oldIndex).Cells(0)
```

Comment: I think the reason why someone down voted you without commenting there reason is because when i tried your code the output is when i click the button the blue selector always go down by one which is not on what i expected. My target here is go back to the current cell after refreshing the row. lets say I edit "bar3" of  ''foo3" and after i edit it i want to return it back to foo3 again

Comment: For now I will up vote your answer so it will return to neutral. Hoping to see the in your post very soon TYSM for future help

Comment: Mine was an example to prove that you can use `.CurrentCell`. I gave you what you needed, you can't pretend me to write the code for you...