# how to optimize a "foreach" event from a gridview in asp.net webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have an `Event` that starts when a `TextBox` text is changed in c#.net.
The `Event` goes over a `GridView` rows. The `GridView` is created with information from a DB. This `GridView` has eight `TemplateFields`, seven with `TextBox` and one with a `DropDownList` control.

The problem is that this Event is taking between 26 and 27 seconds.

### Foreach row, it should:

- Check if the [4] column content is equal to "BATCH" and, if true, paint the
  entire row with a different color.
- Extract the ID from the [0] column.
- Use this ID and the Date from a `TextBox` for a Query that will look
  if the record already exists in the DB.
- If the record exists, it should print it into the `TextBox` and `DropDownList` from the `TemplateField`.
- If some of the records in the database are empty, there's a few
  `TextBox` that shouldn't print it.

### Additional Information:

- The `GridView` is created with data from the DB, using a `QUERY`
  inside a `SqlDataSource`. This happens in the same event. This
  `QUERY` contains some `INNER JOIN`, the data is not stored in the
  same DB Table:

  `SELECT Dealer.IDDealer, Batch.IDBatch, Lpars.Nombre, Dealer.DealerCodigo, Batch.Nombre AS Expr1, Batch.CTStart AS Expr2 FROM Lpars INNER JOIN Dealer ON Lpars.IDLpar = Dealer.IDLpar INNER JOIN Batch ON Dealer.IDDealer = Batch.IDDealer INNER JOIN [1Monday] ON Batch.IDBatch = [1Monday].IDBatch WHERE (Batch.Status = 'Enabled') ORDER BY Batch.CTStart`
- The response time issue is not because the `SQL QUERY` at the top. I tried it
  separatelly and the SQL Server response time for this query is less
  than 2 seconds.
- There is some `DATETIME` data that I extract from the DB. So, before
  I print it into the `TextBox`, I need to change the `DATETIME` format
  to my needs. That's why I store the extracted data into variables
  before print it.

Here is my code:

-

```
 //WHEN THE TEXT FROM TEXTBOX CHANGES:
        protected void TextDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //THE GRIDVIEW IS CREATED:
            GridView1.DataSourceID = DatosLunes.ID;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            //A) I CREATE VARIABLES TO CHARGE THE DATA THAT CAMES FROM THE DATABASE WHEN PROCEED WITH THE QUERY
            string VarsDateGV;
            string VarsStartGV;
            string VarsScchkGV;
            string VarsEndGV;
            string VarsDurationGV;
            string VarsBeforeGV;
            string VarsAfterGV;

            //B) FOREACH ROW, THE PROCESS START TO:
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                //B.1) IDENTIFY EACH CONTROL INTO ROW COLUMNS:
                TextBox DateGV = row.FindControl("DateGV") as TextBox;
                TextBox StartGV = row.FindControl("StartGV") as TextBox;
                TextBox ScchkGV = row.FindControl("ScchkGV") as TextBox;
                TextBox EndGV = row.FindControl("EndGV") as TextBox;
                TextBox DurationGV = row.FindControl("DurationGV") as TextBox;
                HiddenField DedicatedGV = row.FindControl("DedicatedGV") as HiddenField;
                HiddenField NotDedicatedGV = row.FindControl("NotDedicatedGV") as HiddenField;
                DropDownList DropDownGV = row.FindControl("DropDownGV") as DropDownList;
                TextBox BeforeGV = row.FindControl("BeforeGV") as TextBox;
                TextBox AfterGV = row.FindControl("AfterGV") as TextBox;
                DateTime FechaCT1 = DateTime.Parse(TextDate.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                //B.2) IF THE [4] COLUMN STRING IS EQUAL TO "BATCH", THE ROW IS PAINTED
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    string NombreBatch = row.Cells[4].Text;

                    if (NombreBatch == "BATCH")
                    {
                        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.NavajoWhite;
                    }
                }

                //B.3) THE QUERY STARTS
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    // B.3.1) EXTRACTS THE ROW ID FROM [0] COLUMN
                    string IDBatch = row.Cells[0].Text;

                    //B.3.2) USE A DATATABLE TO CHARGE DATA FROM THE QUERY "TRAEFILAHO"
                    CADCATOPS.DSCATOPS.BatchDatos1DataTable Fila = CADCATOPS.CADBatchHandoff.TraeFilaHO(Convert.ToInt32(IDBatch), Convert.ToString(FechaCT1));

                    //B.3.3) FOREACH ROW IN THE DATATABLE, THE DB INFORMATION IS SAVED INTO THE VARIABLES CREATED BEFORE (IN THE "A" ITEM).
                    foreach (DataRow row1 in Fila.Rows)
                    {
                        VarsDateGV = row1["FechaBatch"].ToString();
                        VarsStartGV = row1["Inicio"].ToString();
                        VarsScchkGV = row1["FinDedicado"].ToString();
                        VarsEndGV = row1["FinNoDedicado"].ToString();
                        VarsDurationGV = row1["DuracionBatch"].ToString();
                        DropDownGV.Text = row1["Estado"].ToString();
                        VarsBeforeGV = row1["DuracionBefore"].ToString();
                        VarsAfterGV = row1["DuracionAfter"].ToString();

                        /********* FROM NOW ON:
                         B.3.3.1) I VALIDATE IF THE DATETIME DATA EXTRACTED FROM THE DB EXISTS FOR A FEW ITEMS. IF EXISTS, THE FORMAT IS CHANGED FOR MY NEEDS, AND PRINTED.

                         MAYBE YOU ARE ASKING WHY I VALIDATE IT FOR SEPARATED AND NOT ALL TOGETHER, THIS IS BECAUSE I NEED TO CHECK IT SEPARATELLY. 
                         IF "THIS" DATA DOESN'T EXISTS, DON'T BRING IT TO THE GRIDVIEW, BUT IF "THIS OTHER" DATA EXISTS, I NEED TO SHOW IT.
                         *********/
                        if (VarsDateGV != "")
                        {
                            DateTime VardDateGV = DateTime.Parse(VarsDateGV, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            DateTime VardStartGV = DateTime.Parse(VarsStartGV);
                            DateGV.Text = VardDateGV.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                            StartGV.Text = VardStartGV.ToString("HH:mm");
                        }

                        if (VarsEndGV != "")
                        {
                            DateTime VardEndGV = DateTime.Parse(VarsEndGV);
                            DateTime VardDurationGV = DateTime.Parse(VarsDurationGV);
                            EndGV.Text = VardEndGV.ToString("HH:mm");
                            DurationGV.Text = VardDurationGV.ToString("HH:mm");
                        }

                        if (VarsScchkGV != "")
                        {
                            DateTime VardScchkGV = DateTime.Parse(VarsScchkGV);
                            ScchkGV.Text = VardScchkGV.ToString("HH:mm");
                        }

                        if (VarsBeforeGV != "")
                        {
                            DateTime VardBeforeGV = DateTime.Parse(VarsBeforeGV);
                            BeforeGV.Text = VardBeforeGV.ToString("HH:mm");
                        }

                        if (VarsAfterGV != "")
                        {
                            DateTime VardAfterGV = DateTime.Parse(VarsAfterGV);
                            AfterGV.Text = VardAfterGV.ToString("HH:mm");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } //FOREACH LOOP IS COMPLETED.
        }
```

Do you have any reccomendation to optimize this event?

**UPDATE: ConnorsFan helps me to detect the issue (Thank you).**

**The issue is the query, because it runs 50 times (or the `GridView` lenght). I tried avoiding it and the response was less than 4 seconds. The problem is that I need it to work with the query. Is there a way to optimize the code for it?**

Comment: How many rows are in GridView1.Rows and how many in Filea.Rows ?

Comment: GridView1 has 50 rows. Fila has 1 row.

Comment: Is the query executed 50 times? And is the response time of 2 seconds for the 50 calls of the query?

Comment: Hi ConnorsFan. The query is executed 50 times, one for each row. Now I tried to avoid that query, and the response is much better (4 seconds). 
Now that you help me to find the reason, how can I optimize it?

Comment: Yes - you do the loop and create a Table parameter of all the possible parameters you would send to the Query, then call the query to get one single data set. You can then filter that data set for each subset of the data. In general you should call your database as infrequently as possible, and get all the data you are going to need in that single call. Iteritive database calls will always give very poor performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `TextDate` is outside of the GridView. As I understand it, your inner query returns a single record. You could modify it to return all the records that you will need inside the loop (including the `IDBatch` field), and run it before entering the loop. Inside the loop, you would find the specific record with the primary key (as indicated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1.aspx)).

```
protected void TextDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    CADCATOPS.DSCATOPS.BatchDatos1DataTable AllFila = CADCATOPS.CADBatchHandoff.AllTraeFilaHO(Convert.ToString(FechaCT1));
    AllFila.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { AllFila.Columns["IDBatch"] };

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        ....
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string IDBatch = row.Cells[0].Text;
            DataRow foundRow = AllFila.Rows.Find(IDBatch);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You could make it faster if the records in the DataTable returned by the query are sorted the same way as in the GridView. The row indexes would match, and you wouldn't need to find the row in the DataTable.

**UPDATE**

If the TextBox data can be obtained directly from the data source that populates the GridView, you can eliminate the `foreach` loop (and all the related processing). You can use the second parameter of `Eval` to format the data:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateGV" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FechaBatch", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' ... />
<asp:TextBox ID="StartGV" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Inicio", "{0:HH:mm}") %>' ... />
```

Comment: The GridView is already created outside the foreach (before it), but in the same event, with another query. This works ok, and fast. The issue is inside the foreach. I will update my code to show it better than here.

Comment: I assumed that `CADCATOPS.CADBatchHandoff.TraeFilaHO` is the call that takes time. You could move it outside of the loop.That is my suggestion. I don't know if it can work for you.

Comment: An alternative would be to take the date into account in the query that populates the GridView (if that is possible). You wouldn't need any additional processing.

Comment: I updated my answer to show the alternative method that I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: ConnorsFan, I need to use it inside the loop because it check the row with the ID and the date, and, if the record exists, it's showed in the columns with textbox in the same row. This process should be started over and over again with the gridview lenght.
I have tried using another method to bring the data from DB (with datareader), but it takes exactly the same time than this other method.

Comment: Oh, I just realize that you updated your answer. Let me check it and I will let you know if it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114223/discussion-between-denis-soto-and-connorsfan).

Comment: Finally, this works for me. Thank you ConnorsFan. Sorry for the delay in my response!

Comment: You're welcome! No problem for the delay: the response had to travel from Argentina to Canada. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Then the total number of iterations is around 100 iterations. That shouldn't take very long at all.

Can you use the Stopwatch class on the beginning and end of the event handler and get a total miliseconds count for the execution of the function - at present there doesn't seem to be any reason to expect the code to be slow. We need to separate the execution speed of the code to the time taken to refresh the UI.

Alternatively follow the advice here [How to suspend a DataGridView while updating its columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649995/how-to-suspend-a-datagridview-while-updating-its-columns) to suspend the GridView painting and reformatting during the execution of your changes, then resume the layout after you have finished.