# DataGridView Unwantedly Snaps Back

Tags: c#, datagridview, scrollbar

I apologize in advance if my question is hard to understand because of my broken English.

In my Windows Form Application in C#, I have a `DataGridView` control that keeps showing the most recent table data. With a `Timer` control, it automatically refreshes the table in the `DataGridView`.
Since there are more columns than the `DataGridView` can show at once, there is a `horizontal scrollbar`.

I am  also using `FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex` to get the current scroll position. This way, when the user is browsing the Table with the `scrollbar` and the table refresh occurs, the `scrollbar` can stay where it was before the refresh.

However, there is one problem. Since `FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex` can only store an integer value, when the table's leftmost column *within the view* is not fully shown, it snaps back upon table refresh, so that the leftmost column *within the view* becomes fully shown. This becomes an issue when the user is browsing the rightmost column with the `scrollbar` because upon refresh, it snaps back to display the leftmost column, instead of the rightmost one, that is, the `scrollbar` does not stay at the rightmost position.

Here is the picture. This is what it **should** keep showing upon table refresh:
[image]

As you can see, **Sex** column is fully shown but the leftmost column is halfway shown. When the table refresh occurs, it snaps one column back to show the leftmost column *within the view*. This prevents the user from viewing the `Sex` column's data when the refresh occurs. (Picture below) I think this is because `FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex` stores an integer value, the column position.

[image]

```
private int scrollPositionColumn;
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //Before the update, save the current scrollbar position
    if(MyDGV.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex >= 0){
        scrollPositionColumn = MyDGV.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex;
    }
    UpdateGridView();
}

private void UpdateGridView(){
    /*Some code*/

    //Restore the previous position of the scrollbar
    MyDGV.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = scrollPositionColumn;
    /*Some code*/
}
```

Can someone please give me advice on how to fix this issue?

Here is the simplified code that I have.

Comment: Can you provide more info on `/* some code */` block? If you update cell-by-cell then you don't need to set `FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex` because existing data are updated.

Comment: Instead of updating cell-by-cell, I refresh the whole table each time.

Comment: You should not do that. It is slow and brings obvious unwanted scrollbar manipulation. You should provide internal cache and update only cells that have changed between two consecutive timer events. Using this approach you won't need any manipulation with `FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex`.

Comment: That's very true. By internal cache, could I use a 2-D array or something to temporary store the data before the update?

Comment: That totally depends on your internal data structure and data retreival algorithm. Please provide full and reproducible example so that we can propose the best suitable solution.

Comment: Also what if there are many date update each time the refresh takes place? In the pictures I provided in my post, I am using a fake `DataGridView` data because it is convenient. In my actual application, I have a huge `DataGridView` control and data in many cells constantly change almost every second.

Comment: It completely depends. Solutions vary from [virtualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649995/how-to-suspend-a-datagridview-while-updating-its-columns) to simple update of several cells with `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout`.

Comment: Thank you, vesek, for the ideas!