# how to make the datagridview load faster with Multiple Row query - c# SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, rows

The code:

```
private void suppPopulate()
        {
            byCode.Text = "Supplier Code";
            byDesc.Text = "Supplier";
            DGViewListItems.Columns.Add("custcode", "Customer Code");
            DGViewListItems.Columns.Add("customer", "Customer");

            DGViewListItems.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
            DGViewListItems.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;

            DGViewListItems.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
            DGViewListItems.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

            using (SqlConnection con = db.Connect())
            {
                SqlDataReader rd;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT custcode, custname FROM Customers WHERE type = 'V';", db.Connect());
                rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                int i = 0;
                if (rd.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        DGViewListItems.Rows.Add();
                        DGViewListItems.Rows[i].Cells["custcode"].Value = rd["custcode"].ToString().Trim();
                        DGViewListItems.Rows[i].Cells["customer"].Value = rd["custname"].ToString().Trim();
                    }
                }
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

The SSMS output:

[image]

The output form loads slowly, the rows for the query are over 1000 so I think the cause of the slow load is the number of returned rows? If yes, how do make the load of the datagridview faster?

Comment: If the problem is a slow painting speed, turn on double buffering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE - this answer relates to the first part of the original question regarding why only a single row of the DataGrid being populated.**

Incrementing the counter "i" at the bottom of the while loop looks like it may fix the problem.

You are adding rows, but only updating the first.

Comment: That would definitely help. Regarding performance it would be a good idea to call `SuspendLayout` before starting the update and `ResumeLayout` after.

Comment: @PaulF ohh yeah right didnt notice the increment was not implemented. But do you have solution for the slow load of the table?

Comment: See the comment by @PalleDue.

Comment: See also this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649995/how-to-suspend-a-datagridview-while-updating-its-columns - there is a link to MSDN about improving performance

Comment: And this is why we just more simply load a datatable and bind it to the grid

Comment: The datatable works fine, thanks guys.