# Adding rows to a datatable takes too long

Tags: vb.net, linq, dictionary, datatable, datagridview

```
If reader.AsDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

    Dim DistItemslist As New List(Of Eidos)
    Dim dgv As New DataGridView()
    Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
    Dim cellValue As String = Nothing
    Dim totalLU1 As Double = 0
    Dim totalreserved As Double = 0
    Dim distDT As New DataTable

    Dim distDR As DataRow = Nothing

    dgv.BindingContext = New BindingContext()
    dgv.DataSource = reader.AsDataSet.Tables(0)

    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dgv.Columns
        distDT.Columns.Add(dgv(col.Index, 0).Value)
        'DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgv(col.Index, 0).Value, dgv(col.Index, 0).Value)
    Next

    dgv.Columns.Add("key", "key")
    dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(0)

    For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
        If IsDBNull(dgv(3, i).Value) Then
            dgv(3, i).Value = "0"
        Else
            dgv(3, i).Value = FormatDateTime(dgv(3, i).Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)

            If Split(dgv(3, i).Value, "/")(1) <> "02" Then
                dgv(3, i).Value = "30/" & Split(dgv(3, i).Value, "/")(1) & "/" & Split(dgv(3, i).Value, "/")(2)
            Else
                dgv(3, i).Value = "28/" & Split(dgv(3, i).Value, "/")(1) & "/" & Split(dgv(3, i).Value, "/")(2)
            End If
        End If
            dgv(10, i).Value = dgv(0, i).Value & "#" & dgv(1, i).Value & "#" & dgv(3, i).Value

    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
        If Not dgv.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then
            cellValue = dgv(10, i).Value.ToString()

            If Not dic.ContainsKey(cellValue) Then
                dic.Add(cellValue, 1)
            Else
                dic(cellValue) += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next


    For Each pair In dic

        Dim query = (From row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
                     Where row.Cells(0).Value = Split(pair.Key, "#")(0) AndAlso row.Cells(1).Value = Split(pair.Key, "#")(1) AndAlso row.Cells(3).Value = Split(pair.Key, "#")(2)
                     Select row)

        For Each item In query
            totalLU1 = totalLU1 + CDbl(item.Cells(4).Value)
            totalreserved = totalreserved + CDbl(item.Cells(9).Value)
            'MsgBox(item.Cells(0).Value & " " & item.Cells(1).Value & " " & item.Cells(2).Value & " " & item.Cells(3).Value & " " & item.Cells(4).Value & " " & item.Cells(5).Value & " " & item.Cells(6).Value & " " & item.Cells(7).Value & " " & item.Cells(8).Value & " " & item.Cells(9).Value & " " & item.Cells(10).Value)
            'MsgBox(totalLU1)
            If item Is query.Last Then
                'DistItemslist.Add(New Eidos(item.Cells(0).Value, item.Cells(1).Value, item.Cells(2).Value, item.Cells(3).Value, totalLU1, item.Cells(5).Value, item.Cells(6).Value, item.Cells(7).Value, item.Cells(8).Value, totalreserved))
                'DataGridView1.Rows.Add(item.Cells(1).Value, item.Cells(2).Value, item.Cells(0).Value, item.Cells(3).Value, totalLU1, item.Cells(5).Value, item.Cells(6).Value, item.Cells(7).Value, item.Cells(8).Value, totalreserved)
                distDT.Rows.Add(item.Cells(0).Value, item.Cells(1).Value, item.Cells(2).Value, item.Cells(3).Value, totalLU1, item.Cells(5).Value, item.Cells(6).Value, item.Cells(7).Value, item.Cells(8).Value, totalreserved)
                totalreserved = 0
                totalLU1 = 0
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'DataGridView1.DataSource = DistItemslist

End If
```

Hello there, I would appreciate some help on this one. I'm trying to populate a datable or gridview direclty with the results from a linq query. Unfortunately it's taking too long to complete so I'm wondering if I'm iterating the dictionary in a wrong manner or is it something else which I'm entirely oblivious to...

Edit: The original datasource is about 6000 rows long and it's taken from an excel spreadsheet into a datagridview (dgv) instance. Notice how this assignment is completed within a fraction of a second.

When I'm iterating the dictionary though (For Each pair In dic) to get my custom rows in a datatable it takes a bit less that a minute to complete to produce around 2300 rows.

Edit: To add more context, data consists of items (rows) that have specific codes, dates, and locations among other. What I'm trying to attempt is to concatenate items that have these three elements in common into one thus reducing the size of the table, while adding together (sum) other elements of each item. (not just removing duplicates)

Updated code that uses dictionary as intended:

````
        Dim XLDic As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        Dim SumDT As New DataTable
        Dim value As String
        Dim key As String


        For i As Integer = 0 To XLDT.Columns.Count - 1
            XLDT.Columns(i).ColumnName = XLDT.Rows(0).Item(i).ToString
            SumDT.Columns.Add(XLDT.Rows(0).Item(i).ToString)
        Next

        XLDT.Rows().RemoveAt(0)

        For i As Integer = 0 To XLDT.Rows.Count - 1
            If IsDBNull(XLDT.Rows(i).Item(3)) Then
                XLDT.Rows(i).Item(3) = "-"
            Else
                XLDT.Rows(i).Item(3) = FormatDateTime(XLDT.Rows(i).Item(3), DateFormat.ShortDate)

                If Month(CDate(XLDT.Rows(i).Item(3))) <> 2 Then
                    XLDT.Rows(i).Item(3) = "30/" & Split(XLDT.Rows(i).Item(3), "/")(1) & "/" & Split(XLDT.Rows(i).Item(3), "/")(2)
                Else
                    XLDT.Rows(i).Item(3) = "28/" & Split(XLDT.Rows(i).Item(3), "/")(1) & "/" & Split(XLDT.Rows(i).Item(3), "/")(2)
                End If
            End If
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To XLDT.Rows.Count - 1
            key = XLDT.Rows(i).Item(0)
            value = XLDT.Rows(i).Item(4)
            If Not XLDic.ContainsKey(key) Then
                XLDic.Add(key, value)   
            Else
                XLDic(key) = XLDic(key) & "..."
            End If
        Next


        For Each pair In XLDic
            SumDT.Rows.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value)
        Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = SumDT
    End If
End If```
````

Comment: Define "too long" please. This really needs some numbers: time taken, what you expect, how many rows? Have you done any profiling?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that information. The datasource is about 6000 rows long and it's taken from an excel spreadsheet into a datagridview (dgv) instance. Notice how this assignment is completed within a fraction of a second.

When I'm iterating the dictionary though to get my rows in a datatable it takes a bit less that a minute to complete...

Comment: I think I should be expecting around 1-2 seconds for that no? I haven't done any profiling.

Comment: Added more context

Comment: @kokotas Can you do it without the DataGridView, and only use that for display? UI elements tend to be slow to process. Otherwise, please see [How to suspend a DataGridView while updating its columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649995/how-to-suspend-a-datagridview-while-updating-its-columns).

Comment: @Andrew Morton I see your point but dgv datagridview object is not bound to an ui element. The part which takes long to process is the for each loop where I'm iterating the dictionary. While dgv is being accessed within that loop too, do you think that could be an issue even though it's not updating an ui element?

Comment: In your loop over `dic`, you run a loop over `query` which scans the `dgv.Rows` for every pair in `dic`. (Note that `query` doesn't run until the `For Each` and is run each time around the loop.) Your `query` also runs the `Split` for every row in `dgv` - you would be better doing the `Split` outside the query but I doubt if that is the main performance issue. I expect it is trying to query over the DataGridView rows that is slow.

Comment: Instead of querying over `dgv`, why don't you run a query over `reader.AsDataSet.Tables(0)`?

Comment: @NetMage I ended up starting from scratch. I had misused the dictionary among other things that you also mentioned. The code I have now only iterates the dictionary to add rows in a datatable and then assign it as datasource to a datagridview. It achieves the same result but within fractions of a second. I will update my question. Thanks for pointing to the right direction.