# c# string.replace scroll bar goes to top

Tags: c#, string, winforms, replace

I have a multiline textbox and when I replace its text, the scroll bar goes to top ...

How can I prevent that and keep the scrollbar at the bottom like `AppendText` method in textbox?

My code is as follows:

```
int milisecond = 100;
int persent = 0;
do
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int add = rnd.Next(1, 9);
    int wait = rnd.Next(50, 1000);
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("Progress %" + persent, "");
    persent += add;
    if (persent > 100)
    {
        persent = 100;
    }

    textbox1.AppendText("Progress %" + persent);
    Task.Delay(milisecond).Wait();

    this.Refresh();

} while (persent != 100);
```

Comment: I *knew* that's how progress bars worked! :oP  Out of interest, is this a windows forms application?

Comment: Windows Form , But Like Console Application :P ...

Comment: From what I can tell, the code is possibly executing on the same thread as the UI.  Therefore you are trying to force the screen to update by using the `Refresh()` method.  I would suggest using `BackgroundWorker` to assist you in thread management for code / UI tasks.  It is explained here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Comment: Oh Thanks ! , I Removed this.Refresh() and worked :D , Thanks Again

Comment: No problem - If if the future you wish to run code and update the UI simultaneously (which is the point of progress indicator, I think) then I would strongly recommend BackgroundWorker - its a very handy way to manage this type of threading consideration.

Comment: Actually, `BackgroundWorker` has largely been superseded by `Task`, `await` and `IProgress<T>`. [See this blog from Mr Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html)

Answer (score 0):

add this after the AppendText()

```
        textbox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

Comment: Glitches the program ! , Scrollbar goes to top and then goes to down and again ...

Comment: That's a separate issue - look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550293/stopping-textbox-flicker-during-update